# Bulk Insert and Returning IDs using sqlite

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy

I understand that sqlite doesn't support RETURNING at least that is what sqlAlchemy is telling me:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: RETURNING is not supported by this dialect's statement compiler.
```

I get this error when using sqlAlchemy's Core library. Here is a code example:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=False)

# create table
meta = MetaData(engine)
table = Table('userinfo', meta,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('first_name', String),
    Column('age', Integer),
)
meta.create_all()

# generate rows
data = [{'first_name': f'Name {i}', 'age': 18+i} for i in range(10)]

# this seems to work on PostgreSQL only
stmt = table.insert().values(data).returning(table.c.id)

for rowid in engine.execute(stmt).fetchall():
    print(rowid['id'])
```

Now, when I use similar code with sqlAlchemy's ORM library the IDs are returned. Here is the source code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String

from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()

class UserInfo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "userinfo"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(String)
    age = Column(Integer)


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=False)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

data = [dict(first_name=f'Name {i}', age=18+1) for i in range(10)]
session.bulk_insert_mappings(UserInfo, data, return_defaults=True)

session.commit()

print([s['id'] for s in data])
```

How come that this is working while the Core one is not? When I look at the generated sql I don't see.

Answer (score 1):

After some digging I found this [link](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/_modules/examples/performance/bulk_inserts.html)

In this document the use of bulk_insert_mappings is just `Batched INSERT statements via the ORM "bulk", using dictionaries.`. When setting `return_defaults=True` I assume sqlalchemy is repeatedly `calling upon last row id`. Hence the IDs are available.